# Single call to function with CTE is fast, in SELECT operation, it is slow

Tags: sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression

I have a table that has fields that implement a classic parent/child relationship. A basic table definition looks look as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE tblAssets
(
    fldAssetID int,
    fldParentAssetID int
)
```

Sample data showing a four-level tree would be as follows (though my table has 49 million rows):

```
fldAssetID | fldParentAssetID
-----------------------------
   1       |     NULL
   2       |     1
   3       |     2
   4       |     3
```

So I have a function that returns the progeny count. The progeny counts would be 3, 2, 1 respectively for assetIDs 1, 2, and 3.

Here's the function to count the progeny:

```
    ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_GetProgeny]
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @assetIDToCheck int
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @GetProgeny int

    ;WITH ProgenyCTE AS 
     (
        SELECT
            fldPAssetID
            ,fldParentAssetID
        FROM
            tblAssets WITH (NOLOCK)
        WHERE
            fldParentAssetID = @assetIDToCheck
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            a.fldAssetID
            ,a.fldParentAssetID
        FROM
            tblAssets a WITH (NOLOCK)
            INNER JOIN ProgenyCTE AS BA ON a.fldParentAssetID = BA.fldAssetID
        )

    SELECT @GetProgeny =
        (
            SELECT
                COUNT(DISTINCT fldPatentAssetID)
            FROM
                ProgenyCTE
        ) OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)

    RETURN @GetProgeny
END
```

The function to count progeny works well and fast on a single call. When I put the call into a query (or even a simple while loop), the thing hangs and I see many CX_PACKET waits. This code is super fast:

```
 SELECT 1 ,dbo.udf_GetProgeny(1)
```

While this code will stall out:

```
    SELECT
        fldAssetID
        ,dbo.udf_GetProgeny(fldAssetID)
    FROM
        tblAssets
```

Even the most basic, though ill-advised loop structure hangs up on the 147th call, but all others before that are super fast.

```
DECLARE @counter int = 0

while @counter < 1000
BEGIN
    SELECT @counter, dbo.udf_GetProgeny(@counter) 

    SET @counter = @counter + 1
END
```

I appreciate any insights that you may be able to provide. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A scalar function like this gets executed row by (agonizing) row. With 49 million rows, that's going to take time. You should rewrite the function to an [inline table valued function](https://technet.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/ms189294(v=sql.105).aspx). You can execute that set based, which will be much faster.

Comment: instead of a scalar function why don't you build a CTE that builds all Progeny and then join to the main query

Comment: Parameter sniffing may be an issue. Can you try option recompile? (I still think rewriting the function to an inline tvf is the best way to go).